# Can you dent a metal wall with a feather?

Tags: material-science

I know that theoretically you can only scratch a material with a harder material, but what about denting? While scratching a solid would seem to involve breaking bonds, denting a solid would intuitively seem like bending them, and so should play by different rules.

So the question remains:

Could you, given the right angle, the right force, and only a collection of feathers aimed soft-part-first, dent a metal wall?

Answer (score 1):

You can drill a hole with a water jet, or compressed air, or even with light; I've done all of these. Feathers may be a challenge,  but with enough feathers, and enough force, you can wear away the wall.  A dent is a deformation of the surface; if examined before and after with an AFM, you might be able to find a dent by strain measurements.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't agree with your distinction between scratching and denting. There is some difference, but not so simple. If by denting you mean a *plastic* deformation - one that doesn't go away once you remove the external cause - then this involves some kind of breaking bonds (movement or emergence of impurities, etc.)

If you mean an elastic deformation, then you don't have to *aim* anything, just lay some feathers on a horizontal wall and it will bend down (really, really little - but there *has to be some* cause for the arising reaction that supports the extra weight)

Comment: Scratching usually means that material is abraded away, while a dent is a plastic deformation.  My examples come from working directly with metal and ceramics. My reading of the OP excludes elastic deformation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. simply rest the feather against a flat plate of steel and place a stick of dynamite on top of it. Light fuse, get away, plug ears... and when you are done, a beautifully-detailed image of the feather will be embossed into the surface of the plate.

There are artists who work with steel and dynamite, placing delicate things like dried leaves on the steel plate and setting off the explosive nearby. the results are striking, and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. simply rest the feather against a flat plate of steel and place a stick of dynamite on top of it. Light fuse, get away, plug ears... and when you are done, a beautifully-detailed image of the feather will be embossed into the surface of the plate.

There are artists who work with steel and dynamite, placing delicate things like dried leaves on the steel plate and setting off the explosive nearby. the results are striking (pun intended of course), and beautiful.